# Apache: Using an environment variable in Options directive?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables, directive

I'm trying to configure my htaccess file to set an Options directive to use an environment variable.

I have an environment variable - `SYMLINKS` - set to `+FollowSymLinks` and have used the following directive:

```
Options %{ENV:SYMLINKS}
```

However, I get a 500 server error and the log file reports:

```
.htaccess: Illegal option %{ENV:SYMLINKS}
```

Is what I'm trying to do achievable through another method, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the [*AllowOverride Options* privilege](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Override) in order to set any options.

You can read more here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that's what I'm asking. I would like to use an Apache environment variable to set the value of my option directive. Just further to my comment, I have a Gist here which shows the .htaccess file I'm working with - https://gist.github.com/welly/de9d0a98cc36ebcae9ee. I am trying to set the value of +FollowSymLinks based on an Apache environment variable.